# How to write verilog code if one input has the same value as one output

Tags: verilog

My output is A,B,C,D and input is x,y,z, from the truth table I just made I found that A has the same value as x, how could I express A when writing a verilog descriptive module?
I know from C = x+y I can write

```
AND G1(C,x,y);
```

but what should I do when I don't even need a gate? I can think of 2 ways of writing it, which one makes more sense?

```
module question1(B,C,x,y);
        output B,C,x;
        input x,y;
```

or

```
module question1(A,B,C,y);
        output A,B,C;
        input A,y;
```

Also I want to know if output D has the same value as output C, how could I mention D in the module?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `assign A=x;`?

Comment: From your description, you should **not** have the same variable as input and output. So, have different variables. However in general `inout` is a direction keyword to express ports which are both, inputs and outputs. You might also be able to declare the port as `input` and rely on port `coercion` to make it by-directional. You need to provide more code in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tools require some logic between ports. You can use a `buf` primitive.

```
module question1(output A,B,C,D, input x,y,z);
  buf (A,x);
  ...
endmodule
```

Otherwise, you can use a port expression

```
module question1(output A,B,C,D, input .x(A) ,y,z);

  ...
endmodule
```